# Врождённая грамотность

Tags: общие-вопросы

Вопрос к школьным преподавателям. Наверняка у вас встречались ученики, совершенно не знающие правил, но пишущие без ошибок. У нас про таких учителя говорили, что у них врождённая грамотность. Как вы считаете, существует ли врождённая грамотность или это результат того, что человек много читает и у него хорошая память.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё-таки какая-то генная составляющая есть в любой способности: грамотно писать, умело очистить карманы пассажира, вести задушевную беседу, иметь неотразимое ораторское воздействие на слушателей (какое, говорят, было у Л. Д. Троцкого) и т. д. и т. д. Каждый из нас имел любимых учителей и преподавателей - чаще всего, это чувство возникало от умения учителя проникнуть в душу ученика-обучающегося, что тоже, несомненно, врождённая способность. В общем, чудо, с какой стороны на него ни посмотреть, есть, оно существует, а чудо - это уже нечто врождённое, не материальное, с точки зрения материализма зачастую не объяснимое. Развивать можно только то, что уже имеется (на генном уровне), но у каждого генный запас способностей ограничен. Однако есть более или менее выраженные наклонности ребёнка, которые и используются для его развития. Я никогда не умел рисовать. Единственную четвёрку я получил за рисунок шара во 2-м классе. Ну нет у меня этой способности, хотя скоро перейду на девятый десяток. Я люблю смотреть картины - всю жизнь! Но от этого у меня "художественная" грамотность не усовершенствовалась ни на гран, и  самое большее, я получил бы теперь за свой рисунок шара пятёрку... Вот как-то так, я думаю, надо бы ответить.

Answer (score 3):

Врожденную грамотность можно сравнить с другими способностями - к рисованию, музыке, танцам, спорту. Это хорошая зрительная память, которая на подсознательном уровне фиксирует различия в произношении и написании слова. Люди обладают этой способностью в большей или меньшей степени: так, художественным натурам свойственна интуитивная память, а у математиков на первом месте стоит логическое мышление.

Все наши орографические правила направлены на развитие этой зрительной памяти, так как они просто указывают на орфограммы, обычно не объясняя причин явления.

Преимущества интуитивного и грамматического способов обучения письму активно обсуждались в 20-х годах, и в конечном результате остановились на грамматическом принципе. Однако в действительности мы имеем некий гибрид: мы учим правила, чтобы видеть орфограммы, но потом зрительно запоминаем правильное написание и забываем о правилах - можно сказать, приобретаем определенный уровень  "врожденной грамотности".

Также можно отметить, что люди с врожденной грамотностью не во всех темах ориентируются с одинаковым успехом. Их способности можно сравнить с компьютерной программой, проверяющей грамотность текста. Особенно сложны для них парные варианты (ПРЕ и ПРИ, НЕ и НИ и др.), где одной интуиции бывает недостаточно.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, Вы ответили на вопрос сама. Ни о какой врожденной грамотности не может идти речь. Она является результатом медленного, вдумчивого чтения и практики в написании различных текстов. В младших классах часто дети переписывают готовые тексты, и это тоже старый, добрый способ овладения грамотностью письма.

Answer (score 2):

Врожденной грамотности просто не может быть. Она никогда не проявится у ребенка, равнодушного к чтению. Обычно автоматическая,или привычная, грамотность(так точнее)возникает у детей, рано научившихся читать и много читающих, как говорят, запоем,обладающих хорошей памятью - образной, зрительной,просто "автоматической",у которых постепенно возникает "чутье" на слова, фразы, построение речи. Но, как правило, такие дети, как и все другие, могут допускать ошибки в расстановке знаков препинания, они их ставят по своему усмотрению, как многие взрослые писатели. Это - из личного опыта контактов со многими автоматическими "грамотеями".

Comment: Вообще говоря, "врожденную грамотность" не стоит считать большим преимуществом: кроме автоматизма письма в определенных пределах она мало что дает человеку. Такие люди обычно  не много внимания уделяют изучению языка вообще, часто не любят и не понимают его.

Comment: Позволю себе не согласиться.Не знаю уж какое это "преимущество", но любовь к чтению вообще открывает постепенно перед человеком такой огромный и разнообразный мир, что при наличии определенных, уже генетических предпосылок, биологических талантов люди, оперирующие в мозгу колоссальными объемами информации, способны быть просто гениями науки, или гениями стратегии. Помните "Он в черепе сотней губерний ворочал, людей носил до миллиардов полутора. Он взвешивал мир в течение ночи, А утром...".

Comment: Да, правил эти люди, возможно не помнят, и языковеды из них не всегда получаются, но многогранность восприятия ими мира - необыкновенна.

Answer (score 2):

"Труд создал человека". Любая способность человека развивается путём многочисленных упражнений. Я начал читать с 4-х лет - сводки информбюро в "Правде" (отец был на фронте).К моменту знакомства с грамматикой был стихийно грамотен настолько, что мог сам выводить правила, основываясь на приобретённом словесном багаже. Выражение "врождённая грамотность" неверное: "приобретённое в результате интенсивного чтения с ранних лет". Мне 77. Я хорошо рисую, играю на народных струнных инструментах, семи- и шестиструнной гитаре, клавишных, баяне, кларнете, пишу стихи и музыку, читаю английских писателей в подлиннике, вожу мотоцикл, автомобили любых грузоподъёмностей,тракторы и лодки,владею десятком народных ремёсел, столярным и токарным (по дереву)делом,люблю шахматы,бильярд,волейбол,баскетбол,лыжи (1-й разряд), фехтование (чемпион города 1959 года). В 70 овладел компьютером. Ничего врождённого: отец - из беднейших крестьян, мать - разнорабочая.Никакими талантами не обладали.

Comment: Труд без способностей мало что даст, а то, что Ваши родители не обладали талантами, спорный вопрос. Скорее всего, в силу обстоятельств они не могли их развить.

Comment: Завидую Вашим талантам, но ведь есть же бесталанные! Вы - исключение из правил, а речь идёт о среднестатистическом гражданине РФ. А если среднестатистический человек с отклонениями в отрицательную сторону? Он трудится, трудится, а у него почти не получается, и Ваш пример его не заражает, а формула Ф. Энгельса в нём не работает. Вам это удивительно, и Вы не верите тому, что такие люди, которые работают, работают, а у них ничего не получается (ну, грубо говоря, неудачники) в принципе возможны в реальности... Ваши родители имели такое строение ген, что появились Вы (и слава Господу за это!).

Comment: > Ничего врождённого: отец - из беднейших крестьян, мать - разнорабочая.Никакими талантами не обладали.

Простите ради пардона, но причем тут Ваше происхождение? Я что-то не припомню, чтобы был выявлен генетический материал, ответственный за наследование общих и специальных способностей.
Ну а в остальном я с Вами согласна. Интеллект (без которого освоение языка тоже не обходится), как это ни прискорбно, не развивается, но большинство способностей можно развить.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, грамотность вырастает не только из чтения, но и из знакомства с мелодикой речи. Когда семья читает вслух и поёт песни, когда родители разговаривают друг с другом и с детьми, когда их общение богато интонациями и ритмами, у детей вырабатывается музыкальное чутьё к языку. После этого часть правил оказываются очевидными: запятая ставится не потому, что так велит учебник, а потому, что в этом месте чтец переводит дыхание.